# Can't extract machine code from Cortex-M3 firmware

Tags: arm, reverse-engineering, cortex-m, bare-metal

I want to extract machine code from XBee DigiMesh firmware (Cortex-M3, EM357), so I have SREC file with 3 sections inside. I suppose that one of these sections is a code section, but arm-none-eabi-objdump reports "unknown instruction" very often. **Does anyone know why this happens?**

This is how I try to do this:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy --input-target=srec --output-target=binary -j .sec2 xbp24-dm_8073.ehx2.dec sec2.bin
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -bbinary -marm -Mforce-thumb sec2.bin
```

- Firmware: http://tmp.nazaryev.ru/xbp24-dm_8073.ehx2.dec
- EM357 datasheet: https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/EM35x.pdf

Update: there is answer at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15049/cant-extract-machine-code-from-cortex-m3-firmware

Comment: ask this on the [reverse engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 0):

The cortex-m3 supports thumb2, which is variable instruction length, you cannot simply start at the beginning and disassemble a variable length instruction set you can/will easily get out of sync and the output turns to garbage and remain that way forever.  Likely not in this case, but you will have errors, this is expected.  it is quite possible they added items to confuse a disassembler as well.

Also you could have a lot of data here, or it could be compressed code, or who knows what else...

Being a cortex-m the first chunk of words are not a vector table, so what is this code.  If you examine the output in the way you have used the gnu tools, this does not look like real code, so perhaps encrypted or compressed or other.  Do you see stack frames being built and functions ending with a pop (ldmia) that contains the link register with some static words after that then what looks like the beginning of the next function?  Granted it might not all be compiled code, but some of it should look like compiled code.

if you are trying to hack some firmware you should perhaps figure out how/where this is loaded and create/use an instruction set simulator.  without a vector table to start with though, have fun.

the way you did your disassembly you lost the address content

```
S123110001BE8110204D5401BE96102452...
0x1100 : 0x01BE
0x1102 : 0x8110
0x1104 : 0x204D
0x1108 : 0x5401
0x110C : 0xBE96
0x110E : 0x1024
```

and so on, that or probably byteswapped

```
0x1100 : 0xBE01
0x1102 : 0x1081
```

You could take that srec and create a program:

```
.hword 0xbe01
.hword 0x1081
```

one for each contiguous address range of items, when the address jumps start a new file, create a linker script to cover the start addresses of each section, assemble, make a _start label in one of them, link with the script then you have an elf you can disassemble, I still expect it to be problematic, but some of the relative addressing would make sense and or absolute addressing.

Also note your entry point

```
S903189351
```

assuming that is real, no reason to assume that it is.